# python pyqt5 application high dpi scaling

Tags: python, pyqt5, highdpi

We have built PyQt5 application using PyCharm IDE and executable created using pyinstaller.  The application was built on a monitor with a display resolution of 1536 x 864, here the labels and buttons appear properly.  But when the executable is run on a monitor with display resolution of 1920 x 1080 - the labels and buttons appear overlapping.

Based on the similar question on stackoverflow, I have tried the following suggestions

```
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
```

the above status were added just before

```
APP = QApplication()
```

as well as

```
os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"]   = "1"
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
os.environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"]             = "1"
```

But on the higher resolution screen it is not showing the widgets properly

This issue is only seen when we run the executable file, if we run the project via PyCharm on the higher resolution screen it works fine.

Any suggestions on how to get the executables running on all screen resolutions.

Screenshots of low resolution display settings

[image]

And the UI run from the executable on this screen looks like

[image]

The date fields and the buttons are all visible clearly

Now the screenshots of high resolution laptop

[image]

And the UI run from the executable on this screen looks like

[image]

See the source code for the above UI

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
import traceback

class BlankFormWidgetr(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(BlankFormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_UI()
        self.showMaximized()

    def init_UI(self):
        campaignList = ['Campaign 1', 'Campaign 2', 'Campaign 3']

        self.groupbox = QGroupBox("Get Statistics", self)
        self.groupbox.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10)
        self.groupbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.groupbox.setFixedSize(750, 400)

        self.pagelayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.pagelayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.labelFromDate = QLabel("From Date:", self)
        self.labelToDate = QLabel("To Date:", self)
        self.labelCampaign = QLabel("Campaign:", self)
        self.labelblankoutputwindow = Qlabel("", self)

        self.dateeditFromDate = QDateEdit(calenderPopup=True)
        self.dateeditFromDate.setDisplayFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
        self.dateeditFromDate.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.dateeditFromDate.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

        self.dateeditToDate = QDateEdit(calenderPopup=True)
        self.dateeditToDate.setDisplayFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
        self.dateeditToDate.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.dateeditToDate.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

        self.comboCampaign = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboCampaign.addItems(campaignList)
        self.comboCampaign.setFixedWidth(200)

        self.listboxOutput = QListWidget(self)
        self.listboxOutput.setFixedSize(250, 220)

        self.formlayout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.formlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.formlayout.addRow(self.labelFromDate, self.dateeditFromDate)
        self.formlayout.addRow(self.labelToDate, self.dateeditToDate)
        self.formlayout.addRow(self.labelCampaign, self.comboCampaign)
        self.formlayout.addRow(self.labelblankoutputwindow, self.listboxOutput)

        self.buttongetmonthwisestats = QPushButton('Get Monthwise Stats', self)
        self.buttongetdailyweeklystats = QPushButton('Get Daily / Weekly Stats', self)
        self.buttongetnewordersstats = QPushButton('Get New Orders Stats', self)
        self.buttonGenerateReport = QPushButton('Generate Report', self)
        self.buttonReset = QPushButton('Reset', self)
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton('Close', self)

        self.buttonlayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.buttonlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.buttongetmonthwisestats)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.buttongetdailyweeklystats)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.buttongetnewordersstats)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.buttonGenerateReport)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.buttonReset)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.buttonClose)

        self.pagelayout.addLayout(self.formlayout)
        self.pagelayout.addLayout(self.buttonlayout)
        self.groupbox.setLayout(self.pagelayout)

        self.windowlayout = QVBVoxLayout(self)
        self.windowlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.windowlayout.addWidget(self.groupbox)
        self.show()

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.blank_form_widget = BlankFormWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.blank_form_widget)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"]   = "1"
    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    os.environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"]             = "1"
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
        App.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        App.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

    ex = MyMainWindow()
    App.exec_()
    App.quit()
```

The UI images has scroll bar but in code I have removed it - removing the scroll bar did not have any impact on the dpi issue.

Comment: You are using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), aren't you?

Comment: Hi @musicamante yes I am.  Will it not work with layout managers?

Comment: Hi @musicamante will upgrating from pyqt5 to pyqt6 help as high dpi is enabled by default and cannot be disabled in pyqt6.

Comment: The fact is that according to your information, you're not using high DPI, but very standard resolutions. Can you please provide precise data about those resolutions (in case those were "virtual"), screenshots of the expected and wrong results, and, possibly a [mre] (maybe, the UI file)?

Comment: Hi @musicamante I have uploaded the screenshots and code

Comment: @musicamante did you get a chance to look into the code I have posted?

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't have time to check your code then, and I eventually forgot about it. For starters, I'd completely remove those `setFixedWidth()` calls, since they use completely arbitrary values, and you cannot do that without considering the fact that text can have very different sizes depending on the configuration (without considering the HiDPI aspect, think about font scaling and people with visual impairment). If you want to make widgets as small as possible while still showing all their text content, you must properly use size policies instead of fixed/maximum sizes.

Comment: Then, your second image clearly shows a scroll area that doesn't exist in your code, so please provide a *valid* MRE and check its code more carefully, since it's inconsistent and has various typos. Test the code, ensure that it properly runs (use prompt, as IDEs are often unable to show Qt errors) and is consistent with the issue before submitting an update: we must focus on the problem alone, without being distracted by unrelated issues (for example, `Qlabel` or `QVBVoxLayout`). Simply put, we should be able to copy, paste and run the code without any substantial (or annoying) modifications.